# How can I press enter on keyboard to save my todo

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm wanting to be able to press enter to add my todo, so far clicking button adds it

```
 <h1 style="text-align:center">Todo List</h1>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col col-lg-3">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Todo" aria-label="Enter Todo" aria-describedby="button-addon2" [(ngModel)]="newTodo">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-primary" type="button" id="button-addon2" style="color: white" (click)="saveTodo() ">Add Todo</button>
        
          </div>
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i = index">
                <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
                
                <td class="{{(!todo.isCompleted)?'done':''}}" (click)="done(i)">{{todo.name}}</td>
                <td style="color: red;font-weight: bold;"(click)="remove(i)" class="pointer">X</td>
              </tr>  
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try event binding

```
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="saveTodo()" [(ngModel)]="newTodo">
```

Read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by 2 ways. First way is to use form to enter todo and make save button as `type="submit"` then your todo will be saved as soon as you press enter.
Second way is to use some javascript. like this:-

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input[type='text']");

// Execute a function when the user presses a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("button-addon2").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: i'm not sure it's the same as i'm using angular and typescript